# Calculating gFLOPs of Intel processor

Tags: cpu, intel, processor, flops

How do I measure my computer's gFLOPs per cycle? I am using the following processor- Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G620. It runs @ 2.60 GHz.

Comment: Check Wikipedia on [LINKPACK benchmarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks#The_benchmarks). It's still used for the latest super computers. See also the *LINKPACK* wiki.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jay, I ended up finding an Intel Optimized LINPACK Benchmark package for Windows.

Comment: According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge_(microarchitecture)) it is a SandyBridge. Performance Sandys have AVX with 8 double precision flops per clock per core (theoretic peak with AVX ops: 4 `mul` and 4 `add` per clock); but [ARK](http://ark.intel.com/products/53480) says that in your CPU AVX is disabled. Then theoretical peak is 4 for double precision (SSE2 operations; 2 `mul` and 2 `add`), same as it was in Core 2. To get single precision peak just multiply numbers with 2. In optimized huge-size Linpack it can be possible to achieve up to 80-95% of peak.

Comment: **Pentium/Celeron-brand CPUs don't have AVX**, so cut the throughput in half for SnB.  Or for CPUs where the i3/i5/i7 version has FMA, it's 1/4.